# Hi, i have problem with my code, i want to create a new list from the list

Tags: python, string, list, integer

The elements of the list are integers and strings, I want to convert them to integers first, but the program ignores the command **int(i)** and outputs a list with the same elements as the first list.

```
lista = [2,3,4,'5','6','7']
lista_2 = []
for i in lista:
    int(i)
    lista_2.append(i)
print(lista_2)
```

Comment: It doesn't ignore it, you do, and then just append the original value

Comment: Alternatively: `lista_2 = list(map(int, lista))`.

Comment: Did you run the code?

Answer (score 4):

You are appending the original value. It needs to be stored in some variable or appended while converting to int.

Here is one approach: using a variable

```
lista = [2,3,4,'5','6','7']
lista_2 = []
for i in lista:
    converted = int(i)
    lista_2.append(converted)
print(lista_2)
```

Here is another approach: converting while appending

```
lista = [2,3,4,'5','6','7']
lista_2 = []
for i in lista:
    lista_2.append(int(i))
print(lista_2)
```

There are also other approaches like list comprehension:

```
lista = [2,3,4,'5','6','7']
lista_2 = [int(item) for item in lista]
print(lista_2)
```

or using map and passing int as a function to it:

```
lista = [2,3,4,'5','6','7']
lista_2 = list(map(int,lista))
print(lista_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

*int(n)* does not modify *n* - it returns an integer after converting *n* in accordance with certain rules. See: [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)

In your case, this is better implemented as a list comprehension as follows:

```
lista = [2,3,4,'5','6','7']

lista_2 = [int(n) for n in lista]

print(lista_2)
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is:

```
int(i)
```

it should be:

```
i = int(i)
```